# Parsing nested JSON string in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am logging to logstash,in json format,
my logs have the following fields, each field is a string and the `atts` field is a stringified json (note: `atts` sub fields are different each time)

here is an example:

`{"name":"bob","last":"builder", "atts":"{\"a\":111, \"b\":222}"}`

I would like to parse it to something like this:

```
   {
     "name" => "bob",
     "last" => "builder"
     "atss" => {
          "a" => 111,
          "b" => 222}
   }
```

here is my configuration:

```
input { stdin { } }  

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "parsed"
  }
}
 output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  }}
```

ok, 
so now I get this:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-05T12:19:04.090Z,
    "parsed" => {
        "atss" => "{\"a\":111, \"b\":222}",
        "name" => "bob",
        "last" => "the builder"
    },
        "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "0.0.0.0"
}
```

how can I parse the `atts` field to json so I receive:

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-04-05T12:19:04.090Z,
    "parsed" => {
        "atss" => 
           {"a" => 111,
            "b" => 222},
        "name" => "bob",
        "last" => "the builder"
    },
        "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

thanks to @Alcanzar here is what I did

```
input { 
  stdin { } 
}  

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "message"
  }
  json {
    source => "[message][atts]"
    target => "[message][atts]"
  }

}
 output { stdout { codec => rubydebug  }}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a `json` filter.  Just pass it the field you want to parse and a target where you want it.

Something like:

```
json {
  source => "[parsed][atss]"
  target => "[parsed][newfield]"
}
```

I'm not sure if you can put atss as new field.  It might or might not work.  If it doesn't, use the `mutate` filter to `remove_field` and `rename_field`.

Comment: thanks! can you see my posted answer, is there a way to do this writing the filter all under `json` filter once? something like  `filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "message"
    source => "[message][atts]"
    target => "[message][atts]"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

As of August 5 2020, In logstash 7.8.0, the JSON filter now parses nested strings.
I had the following string stored in a Postgres column, lets call it "column-1"

```
{ "XYZ" : {"A" : "B", "C" : "D", "E" : "F"} }
```

My json filter looked like this

```
json {
    source => "column-1"
    target => "column-1"
}
```

And it was parsed as a nested dictionary in my Elasticsearch Index

The difference from the accepted answer is that now we just need a single json filter instead of multiple ones.